# How to convert a specific query into Laravel Query syntax

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to change the following query to laravel :

```
SELECT 
*


FROM
usrusrs uu
,posts p


WHERE 
(
uu.user_id = $u_id
or
uu.friend_id = $u_id
)
and
(
uu.user_id = p.user_id
OR
uu.friend_id = p.user_id  
)
```

I tried the following, but it's giving different output. I think there might be something wrong with the joining between the two tables. any suggestions ?

```
           $usrusrmembs = DB::table('usrusrs')
                    ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'usrusrs.user_id')
                    ->orwhere('posts.user_id', '=', 'usrusrs.friend_id')
                    ->where('usrusrs.user_id', $u_id)
                    ->orwhere('usrusrs.friend_id', $u_id)                   
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Wherever you see `(x OR y)` in your query, you need to do a `->where(function($query) { $query->where(x); $query->orWhere(y); })` to enclose the set in parentheses.

Comment: You'll also want to consider using Laravel relationships instead of a join. It'll make a lot of Laravel things easier.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I'm not sure how to do the join part using the method you mentioned.

Comment: Your `User` model would have a `function posts() { return $this->hasMany(Post::class); }`, which allows you to do things like `$user->posts` and `User::whereHas('posts')`. (That's the basics; far more complicated setups/queries are 100% possible.) https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Got it after some digging :

```
      $usrusrmembs = DB::table('usrusrs')
                ->join('posts', function ($join) {
                   $join->on('posts.user_id', '=', 'usrusrs.user_id')->orOn('posts.user_id', '=', 'usrusrs.friend_id');
                    })
                ->where('usrusrs.user_id', $u_id)
                ->orwhere('usrusrs.friend_id', $u_id)                   
                ->get();
```